# pass multiple arrays; ajax to webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax

I would like to pass 2 javascript string arrays 
"myArray1" and "myArray2" from ajax to a webmethod. What I have is the following which is not working.

```
var myArray1 = new Array();    
var myArray2 = new Array();    
// the arrays are filled further in the code.   
// call to the webmethod:
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mypage.aspx/SavePage",
        data: ??????,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
```

I do not know how to pass these arrays in the `data:` part of the call.

C# part of my code.

```
public static string SavePage(List<string> myArray1, List<string> myArray2)
{
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
data: "{'myArray1':"+JSON.stringify(myArray1)+",'myArray2':"+JSON.stringify(myArray2)+"}",
```

In your codebehind :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SavePage(List<string> myArray1, List<string> myArray2)
{
return myArray1;
}
```

Comment: @coder, I keep getting (Internal server error) alert followed by success alert for this EXACT example, and the web method break point doesn't hit, any suggestion? I'm using JQuery 1.10.2

Comment: @Abeer Sul - may be check this is [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] present before the webmethod in your case if that's not the case post the code and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
    url: "mypage.aspx/SavePage",
    data: { myArray1: myArray1, myArray2: myArray2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {};
data.myArray1= myArray1;
data.myArray1= myArray2;

var json = JSON.stringify(data);

 $.ajax({
    ... 
    data: json,
     ...
 });
```